# How to get the rank of a student based on his total marks by using rownum function in JSP?

Tags: java, html, jsp, send

I have the following code:

```
try
{
    Connection con=dbConnect.getConnect();
    Statement st=con.createStatement();
    String department = request.getParameter("department");

    ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT  rank,id,sname,firstsem,secondsem,thirdsem,fourthsem,fifthsem,sixthsem, sum(firstsem+secondsem+thirdsem+fourthsem+fifthsem+sixthsem) as total from pg where department='" + department + "' group by id order by total DESC ");%>

    <table cellpadding="10" border="2" >
        <tr>
            <td><b>RANK</b></td>
            <tr>
                <td><b>STUDENT ID</b></td>
                <td><b>STUDENT NAME</b></td>
                <td><b>1St Sem</b></td>
                <td><b>2Nd Sem</b></td>
                <td><b>3Rd Sem</b></td>
                <td><b>4Th Sem</b></td>
                <td><b>5Th Sem</b></td>
                <td><b>6Th Sem</b></td>
                <td><b>Total</b></td>
            </tr>
            <% while(rs.next())
            {%>
            <td>
                <tr>
                    <td><%=rs.getString(1)%></td>
                    <td><%=rs.getString(2)%></td>
                    <td><%=rs.getString(3)%></td>
                    <td><%=rs.getString(4)%></td>
                    <td><%=rs.getString(5)%></td>
                    <td><%=rs.getString(6)%></td>
                    <td><%=rs.getString(7)%></td>
                    <td><%=rs.getString(8)%></td>
                    <td><%=rs.getString(9)%>        
                        <%} %>
                    </table>
                <%}
```

Comment: help me to that code

Comment: Can you give some example of data you really have and you want?

Comment: Can you not add `rownum` to your select statement ? *SELECT  rownum,rank,id,sname,*

Comment: 530,450,458,789 these are the final marks of students

Answer (score 0):

Looks like 
1) you would have to add all the semester numbers to get total marks for all students. 
2) you would have to assign every student a rank based on total marks.
3) Then you would be able to display/save results.
You can use scriptlets in JSP to do all this

Answer (score 0):

Get the query that you are writing in the code to some sql client like oracle sql developer, if you are using oracle db server and test your result first.